# PowerMock.expectPrivate behavior

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, powermock, easymock

I am writing test cases using EasyMock and PowerMock, and I want to modify the behavior of a private method so I am using below

```
PowerMock.expectPrivate(myClass, "m2", "Hello").andReturn("Something");
```

Now when this expect private statement is executed, it is actually invoking the ***REAL*** method.

This real method invocation is causing an issue because the private method has a few variables which are not available during the test execution and that's the reason why I want to mock this private method!

Above is defeating the purpose of private method mocking!!! Is that correct?

Below is my example class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ReplicatePrivateMock.class})
public class ReplicatePrivateMock {

    @Test
    public void testPrivate() throws Exception {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        PowerMock.expectPrivate(myClass, "m2", "Hello").andReturn("Something");
        System.out.println(myClass.m1("Hello"));
    }

    private class MyClass {
        private StringBuilder builder;

        public String m1(String s) {
            return m2(s);
        }

        private String m2(String s) {
            return builder.append(s) + s;
        }
    }
}
```

In this, I am mocking the call to m2() method but that throws NPE because m2 is using `builder` variable which is null!

Please let me know how to ***ACTUALLY*** mock the private method. Thanks very much.

Comment: I´m doing unit tests long time now and there is one personal rule for me: never use `powerMock` and `easyMock`. There´s a reason why this isn´t integrated in jdk like junit and mockito. just write a normal test with normal mocks. you need to write a test for method `m1()` and you add private code into test of this because you can´t enter it. it´s more work but you don´t need a test for `m2()` which give you this time.